# How can I make folder available to only VB.NET application?

Tags: php, vb.net

I have build a VB.NET application which uses PHP command line to run some scripts in a folder in the same directory.

I do not want the script in PHP directory to be editable. So, I want that folder to be inaccessible by users or only available to my applicaiton.

Any Idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I totally understand the architecture of your solution, but it sounds like maybe you could use an IsolatedStorageFile? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Will the System.IO.File class do the trick?

[link text][1]

[1]: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/31134-modify-file-attributes/"System.IO.File on DreamInCode.Net"